# Object Variable or With Block variable not set Error no 91 and Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed error no 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I have created following programme to run a report using the Excel 2010. However this utility runs without any problem for one time. If i close the report and once again runs the following it gives error at line no 26 showing that the " **Object Variable or With block variable not set**" and at line no 28 "**Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed**". If I close the whole programme and runs once again as new use then it works properly. The basic problem while formatting the excel like Bold, Italics Size of the font etc. Please help me to rectify the problem

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()
Dim excelApp As excel.Application
Dim excelWB As excel.Workbook
Dim excelWS As excel.Worksheet
Dim rowCounter As Integer
Dim SL As Integer
Dim RL As Integer
RL = 2

Dim list(7) As String
SL = 0
Dim strFileName As String

'On Error Resume Next: Err.Clear

If Text2.Text <> "" Then
    Data3.RecordSource = "Select ALLOTDATE,BUDGETCODE,BUDGETSCHEME,DCB_Type,ALLOTSLNO,ALLOTMENT,SchemeFull,year1 from budget where allotment >0 and ALLOTDATE >= #" + Text36.Text + "#  and ALLOTDATE <= #" + Text37.Text + "# and budgetcode='" + Text2.Text + "' order by budgetcode "
    Data3.Refresh
Set OL = DB.OpenRecordset("Select ALLOTDATE,BUDGETCODE,BUDGETSCHEME,DCB_Type,AllotSlNo,ALLOTMENT,SchemeFull from budget where allotment >0 and ALLOTDATE >= #" + Text36.Text + "#  and ALLOTDATE <= #" + Text37.Text + "#  and budgetcode='" + Text2.Text + "' order by budgetcode")
End If

If Not Data3.Recordset.EOF Then
    Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    excelApp.Visible = True
    excelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set excelWB = excelApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set excelWS = excelWB.Worksheets(1)
    excelWS.Name = "Allotment Rcpt"
    excelWS.Tab.Color = 220

    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    excelWS.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Statement Showing the Allotment(Target) Received during the year " + Data3.Recordset.Fields(7) + " under various Budget Heads"
    Set A = Range("A1:F1")
    A.MergeCells = True
    A.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    A.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    With Selection.Font
        .Size = 10
        .Italic = False
        .Bold = True
        .Underline = False
        .Underline = False
        .Name = "Arial Black"
    End With
    Set A = Nothing

excelWS.Rows(1).RowHeight = 30
excelWS.Rows(2).RowHeight = 30

excelWS.Cells(3, 1).Value = "Sl No"
excelWS.Cells(3, 2).Value = "Date of Receipt "
excelWS.Cells(3, 3).Value = "Allotment Sl No"
excelWS.Cells(3, 4).Value = "Head of Account"
excelWS.Cells(3, 5).Value = "Amount"
excelWS.Cells(3, 6).Value = "Type of Allotment"
excelWS.Range(excelWS.Cells(3, 1), excelWS.Cells(3, 6)).Select
With Selection.Font
    .Size = 10
    .Italic = False
    .Bold = True
    .Underline = False
    .Name = "Arial Black"
End With
excelWS.Rows(3).RowHeight = 25

Range("A3:F3").Select
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With

While Not Data3.Recordset.EOF
    RL = RL + 1
    SL = SL + 1
    c = SL + 4
    list(1) = SL
    list(2) = Format(Data3.Recordset.Fields(0), "DD-MMM-YYYY")
    list(3) = Val(Data3.Recordset.Fields(4))
    list(4) = Data3.Recordset.Fields(1) + "-" + Data3.Recordset.Fields(2)
    list(5) = Data3.Recordset.Fields(5)
    list(6) = Left(Data3.Recordset.Fields(3), Len(Data3.Recordset.Fields(3)))

    excelWS.Cells(RL + 1, 1).Value = list(1)
    excelWS.Cells(RL + 1, 2).Value = list(2)
    excelWS.Cells(RL + 1, 3).Value = list(3)
    excelWS.Cells(RL + 1, 4).Value = list(4)
    excelWS.Cells(RL + 1, 4).Select
    With Selection
        .WrapText = True
        End With

excelWS.Rows(RL + 1).RowHeight = 16
excelWS.Cells(RL + 1, 5).Value = Format(list(5), "#,###.00")
excelWS.Cells(RL + 1, 6).Value = list(6)
                                    'open the file to receive data
Data3.Recordset.MoveNext
Wend

Range("A:F").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

Range("A:A").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
excelWS.Columns("B:C").ColumnWidth = 18
excelWS.Columns("E:F").ColumnWidth = 20
excelWS.Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 35

excelWS.Cells(c, 4).Value = "Grand Total"

c = c - 1
c = Format((c), "")
excelWS.Cells(c + 1, 5).Value = "=SUM(E4:E" + c + ")"
c = c + 1
Range("B:B").IndentLevel = 1
Range("E:F").IndentLevel = 1
Range("C:D").IndentLevel = 1
excelWS.Cells(c, 4).Select
With Selection.Font
    .Size = 10
    .Italic = False
    .Bold = True
    .Underline = False
    .Name = "Arial Black"
End With
Range("A2").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
excelWS.Cells(c, 5).Select
With Selection.Font
    .Size = 10
    .Italic = False
    .Bold = True
    .Underline = False
    .Name = "Arial Black"
End With
Range("A2").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft


excelWS.Range(excelWS.Cells(c, 1), excelWS.Cells(c, 6)).Select
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With

excelWS.Rows(c).RowHeight = 25
excelWS.Columns(1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
excelWS.Columns(2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
excelWS.Columns(3).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
excelWS.Columns(4).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
excelWS.Columns(5).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
excelWS.Columns(6).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
excelWS.Cells(2, 6).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight

'Save and close
  strFileName = (A_DDOSetup.Text1.Text) + "\6_Excel Reports\Target-Rcpt.xlsx"
    excelWB.SaveAs FileName:=strFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    Set excelApp = Nothing
Set excelWB = Nothing
Else
MsgBox "Record not Found"
End If
```

End Sub

WHILE i RUN THE ABOVE PROGAMME 2ND TIME, I GET AN ERROR IN THE FOLLOWING LINES
i TRIED ADDING OPTION EXPLICIT AND DECLARED OBJECT, STILL PROBLEM CONTINUES
MERGE, FONT SIZE, BOLD LIKE FORMATTING COMMANDS DOES NOT WORK, HOWEVER THE DATA WILL BE DISPLAYED

```
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
excelWS.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Statement Showing the Allotment(Target) Received during the year " +    Data3.Recordset.Fields(7) + " under various Budget Heads"
Set A = Range("A1:F1")
A.MergeCells = True
A.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
A.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
With Selection.Font
    .Size = 10
    .Italic = False
    .Bold = True
    .Underline = False
    .Underline = False
    .Name = "Arial Black"
End With
Set A = Nothing
```

**Thank you for Stackoverflow**, 
**I got the problem Solved**
.Select and with Selection should be removed and the code to be placed directly to range

```
 **old Code**

 excelWS.Cells(c, 4).Select
 With Selection.Font
    .Size = 10
    .Italic = False
    .Bold = True
    .Underline = False
    .Name = "Arial Black"
End With

**Rectified Code**
With excelWS.Cells(c, 4).Font
    .Size = 10
    .Italic = False
    .Bold = True
    .Underline = False
    .Name = "Arial Black"
End With
```

sous2817

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264837(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Can you please write only the lines where the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

can't you just post the line that produces the error?

you have a with .selection.font but no where have you performed a valid selection.

```
try adding RAnge(yourRAnge).select
```

before

```
With Selection.Font
    .Size = 10
    .Italic = False
    .Bold = True
    .Underline = False
    .Underline = False
    .Name = "Arial Black"
End With
Set A = Nothing
```

PS: oh, i strongly recommend you to add "Option Explicit" in your code. at least it will force you to declare variables before using. one more thing, always use **Object.property.value**